# Im trying to find a way to make this work it is trying to counts the amount of times a phrase appears in a line by line text file

Tags: python, list

Whenever I run this code it tells me an error appeared what do I need to do to get it to tell me the amount of times a team appears in a list. The list that is given is[WorldSeriesWinners](https://learn-us-east-1-prod-fleet01-xythos.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/5beddfe10b70f/15695735?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27WorldSeriesWinners.txt&response-content-type=text%2Fplain&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200307T014113Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=21600&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAZH6WM4PLTYPZRQMY%2F20200307%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=63c72c907c403b84c85adc788dfbae07aa9fac1e8f592b7120e0ddad6eebc170).
    wins = 0

```
try:
    input_file = open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt')
    team = input('Enter the team name: ')
    winner = input_file.readlines()
    for i in range(len(winner)):
        winner[i] = float(winner[i])
        if team in winner[i]:
            wins += 1
    print('The team ', team, ' won ', wins, ' World Series')

except IOError:
    print('The file could not be found.')
except IndexError:
    print('There was an indexing error.')
except:
    print('An error occurred.')
```

Comment: What error? Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging? As an aside, using a bare `except` like that is bad practice, be careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... you shouldn't convert the winner name into a `float`. Also, you shouldn't use `in` in case the user passes in a single character. Here is the updated code:

```
wins = 0
input_file = open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt', 'r') # Specify to read file
team = input('Enter the team name: ')
winner = input_file.read().split("\n") # Removes "\n" on each line
for i in range(len(winner)):
    if winner[i] == team: # Check if inpout is equal instead of inside string
        wins += 1
print('The team', team, 'won', wins, 'World Series')
```

Comment: The comment in the code helped me understand the usage of those specific functions. This solved the errors I was facing.

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering what you are asking here, but I couldn't help suggesting a more pythonic way of implementing this:

```
with open('WorldSeriesWinners.txt', 'r') as f:
    winners = [team.rstrip() for team in f.readlines()]

team = input('Enter the team name: ')

print(f'{team} won {winners.count(team)} world series')
```

Some quick explanation:

- `f.readlines()` is a list of all the lines (stored as strings). These however include the new line character '\n'. The method `.rstrip()` gets rid of whitespace in the beginning or end of a string, including new lines.
- `[team.rstrip() for team in f.readlines()]` is what we call a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).
- The `count()` method counts the number of occurences of a potential element; 
  `winners.count('New York Yankees')` returns the number of times the Yankees appear in the list.
- The string `f'{team} won {winners.count(team)} world series'` is what we call an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) (implemented in Python 3.6 and above). It is an extremely convenient equivalent to `'{} won {} world series'.format(team, winners.count(team)`, so keep it in mind.

Comment: Nice and compact, and pythonic. Great!

Answer (score -1):

do `for winner in winners` instead of `for i in range(len(winner)):`

Comment: The same result arises; this is just a "more pythonic" way of doing things, but it doesn't answer the question.